# SQL - Unable to correctly calculate a SUM

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying for days this SQL statement.

I have a DB made for sales and all I need to do is:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(orders.total) as total, orders.transaction_date as date, 
  orders.id as orderid, orders.employee_id as empl 
from orders GROUP by orders.employee_id
```

This query is perfect it gives me all I need. However I need to add the quantity that has been sold so far that correspongs to this query:

```
SELECT order_id, SUM(quantity) 
FROM order_items 
Group By order_id
```

Which is also fine. Both work perfectly, but I need them into one sql statement.

When I try

```
SELECT 
  SUM(order_items.quantity), 
  SUM(orders.total) as total, 
  orders.transaction_date as date, 
  orders.id as orderid, 
  orders.employee_id as empl 
from 
  orders, order_items 
where 
  order_items.order_id = orders.id 
GROUP by 
  orders.employee_id
```

Everything seems correct, except for the total. I have no idea why this is happening.

This is the DB

orders:

```
id | employee_id | transaction_date | total
```

order_items:

```
order_id | quantity
```

Comment: Best practice: Do NOT use `orders, order_items where order_items.order_id = orders.id`. instead use `joins` like `orders inner join order_items on order_items.order_id = orders.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to aggregate the two tables separately *before* joining them together:

```
select sum(oi.quantity), sum(o.total) as total, 
       o.employee_id as empl 
from orders o join
     (select oi.order_id, sum(oi.quantity) as quantity 
      from order_items oi
      group by oi.order_id
     ) oi
     on oi.order_id = o.id 
group by o.employee_id;
```

It doesn't make sense to include the transaction date and order id in the `select`.  You are aggregating by employee id, so there are (likely to be) multiple values for these columns.

Comment: Yup, some databases like Postgres will throw an error if columns other than those in the GROUP BY are present without aggregation.

Comment: Wow, you are the best. Worked perfectly. Excellent. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You're joining on `order_id` but grouping by `orders.employee_id`. Do all `order_items` have the same employee for a given order? Check your relation without the GROUP BY. I doubt `employee_id` is consistent between both `orders` and `order_items`. Posting a sample of your data  may help shed more light on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have two different `GROUP BY` statements between the first two queries, but they aren't both reflected in the merged query.

```
SELECT 
  SUM(order_items.quantity) as quantity, 
  SUM(orders.total) as total, 
  orders.transaction_date as date, 
  orders.id as orderid, 
  orders.employee_id as empl 
from 
  orders
LEFT JOIN
  order_items
ON
  orders.order_id = order_items.order_id
where 
  order_items.order_id = orders.id 
GROUP by 
  orders.employee_id, orders.order_id
```

However, this query still doesn't make sense.  Each row would be a summary of all the orders and order items under one employee_id.  So transaction_date or order id make no sense to select, because that would only give you the first order in the aggregate.